# set a table in a specific sheet of Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code that adds a table in google sheets form the data based on the URL in the code. The current code creates tables in the currently active sheet.  but from the variable "response3", I need to create a table in a particular sheet, not the active one. Exactly,  I need a create a table from response3 in the sheet called "sheet3".

Here is my code:

```
   
var response3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://tabulation.dooblo.net/dAPI/Tabulation/GetSurveyTabulationData?ticket=ebc02621-579b-43ed-ab78-001383a46169&variable=Q_3",params);
  Logger.log(response3.getContentText());
var csvData3 = Utilities.parseCsv(response3);
var sheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet3.getRange(1, 8, csvData3.length, csvData3[0].length).setValues(csvData3);
}
```

I tryied with next code but did not work:

```
var response3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://tabulation.dooblo.net/dAPI/Tabulation/GetSurveyTabulationData?ticket=ebc02621-579b-43ed-ab78-001383a46169&variable=Q_3",params);
  Logger.log(response3.getContentText());
var csvData3 = Utilities.parseCsv(response3);
var sheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName("sheet3");
sheet3.getRange(1, 8, csvData3.length, csvData3[0].length).setValues(csvData3);
```

Anyone could help me with it?

Thanks so much in advance,

Comment: Provide clear problem statement. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

### It is either the `getActiveSheet()` or `getSheetByName()` - not both

What you probably try to do is to get a sheet by name on the active **spreadsheet**,

so:

```js
var sheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet3");
```